# weyl group act by conjugation?

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

let $W$ be a weyl group and $\alpha\in R$ we have $s_{w(\alpha)}=ws_{\alpha}w^{-1}$, to prove this the author says $ws_{\alpha}w^{-1}$ acts as identity on $wL_{\alpha}=L_{w(\alpha)}$ , and $ws_{\alpha}w^{-1}(w(\alpha))=-w(\alpha)$ , I really dont understand why, could any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ws_\alpha w^{-1}\cdot wL_\alpha=w s_\alpha L_\alpha=w L_\alpha$
and
$w s_\alpha w^{-1}(w(\alpha))= w s_\alpha (\alpha) = w(-\alpha)=-w(\alpha)$.

Comment: thank you but I need to show $s_{w(\alpha)}=ws_{\alpha}w^{-1}$

Comment: Yes, and the above calculations show that $ws_\alpha w^{-1}$ does exactly the same thing we would expect from $s_{w(\alpha)}$.

Comment: But didn't you only show the action of $ws_{\alpha}w^{-1}$ on $wL_{\alpha}$? Don't we need to show that $s_{w(\alpha)}=ws_{\alpha}w^{-1}$ on all of $E$? I'm still a bit confused as well, could you expand your thoughts? I'd really appreciate it.